# How to remove the default blue border of the buttons once yo do onblur?

Tags: css

[youtubevolumebar](http://screencast.com/t/hXbNEG5jR5o)

I was on YouTube and randomly playing with the tab button on my Mac, and I see that they are styling the buttons of the navigation bar below the videoplayer, I mean, when you do the onblur, the default blue color on the borders dissapear, and there you will see a yellow border instead.

How can I do it with css?

Check the image http://screencast.com/t/hXbNEG5jR5o.

Comment: The Youtube player isn't an HTML element, it's a flash object.  You cannot apply CSS to objects inside of a Flash object.

Comment: Yes, but the question is: Is possible to do that with any other html element when yo do onblur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the same time, Youtube is a HTML5 player. So, you can apply CSS on the player.

Sound area class is `ytp-volume-hover-area` and its HTML:

```
<span class="ytp-volume-hover-area" draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag: none;"><div class="ytp-volume-control" draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag: none;"><div class="ytp-button ytp-button-volume" role="button" tabindex="6100" aria-label="sesi aç değiştir" data-value="off"></div><div class="ytp-volume-panel" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" tabindex="6200" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuetext="85% ses düzeyi sessiz"><div class="ytp-volume-slider" draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag: none;"><div class="ytp-volume-slider-foreground" style="left: 0px;"></div></div></div></div><div class="ytp-time-display html5-control" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ytp-time-current">0:03</span><span class="ytp-time-separator"> / </span><span class="ytp-time-duration">2:15</span><span class="ytp-time-live-badge">Live</span></div></span>
```

You can apply CSS via `!important` if player has on your website. It is not a good solution but it is a solution.